# To open accordion panel multiple tabs by default

Tags: jsf, primefaces

By default accordion panel opens first tab only, in case of multiple tabs. I want to open custom index tabs by default.

Answer (score 14):

In case of 3 tabs in accordion panel, I tried following and it worked.

```
<p:accordionPanel multiple="true" activeIndex="1,2">
```

accordion panel tabs starts with index 0, so to open 2nd and 3rd tab by default use "1,2" in activeIndex attribute.

Comment: Do you know if index "-1" is valid (to select last "element") ?